# Program on Ubuntu Not Working

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, canopy

I reinstalled a program called Canopy on my Ubuntu for Windows. However, when I call it this happens:

```
<jp2nyy>: ~/Canopy/canopy -d
If Canopy doesn't start correctly, please run with -d option & report the output
/home/jp2nyy/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.7.4.3348.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py:100: UserWarning: Setting kernel_cmd is   deprecated, use
kernel_spec to start different kernels.
warnings.warn("Setting kernel_cmd is deprecated, use kernel_spec to "

/home/jp2nyy/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.7.4.3348.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/canopy_platform/store/store.py:282: UnableToAccessRepositoryWarning: unable to access repository "enthought/commercial"

QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: Invalid argument
Invalid argument (src/tcp_address.cpp:171)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It is driving me insane as I want to access it in order to fully use Python

Answer (score 1):

`inotify` has been problematic for the Windows Subsystem for Linux.  However, things have recently (as of October 2016) improved somewhat.

## Further reading

- [Build 14926](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes#build-14926).  *Windows Subsystem for Linux release notes*.  Microsoft corporation.

Comment: Any idea of how to apply Build 14926 @JdeBP.

Comment: Build #14926 was a Windows 10 Insider build prior to Win10 Creators Update shipping. If you're keen to get early access to what will be shipped in the next version of Win10, Windows Insiders is the place to be :)

Comment: Support for `inotify` was [introduced in Windows 10 Insiders build #14942](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/10/07/wsl-adds-inotify-filesystem-change-notification-support/)